# Java NPE - help on getting rid of it

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I currently got the following piece of code:

```
captureFile = theCaptureFile;
    // If there is only 1 currency it gets the total right away
    if (captureFile.getTotalMoney().size() == 1) {
        Money totalMoney = captureFile.getTotalMoney().values().iterator().next();
        totalAmount  = totalMoney.getAmount();
        currencyCode = totalMoney.getCurrencyCode();
    }
    // If there is more than one currency, goes through every one, converts it to GBP and adds it to the total amount
    else if (captureFile.getTotalMoney().size() > 1) {
        Map<String, Money> totals = captureFile.getTotalMoney();

        for (Entry<String, Money> money : totals.entrySet()) {
            try {
                totalAmount = totalAmount + money.getValue().getEquivalent(BASE_CURRENCY).getAmount();
            } 
            catch (CurrencyNotFoundException e) {
                LOG.error("Getting ExchangeRate:", e);
                totalAmount = null;
                break;
            } 
            catch (ExchangeRateNotFoundException e) {
                LOG.error("Getting ExchangeRate:", e);
                totalAmount = null;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

When the code gets called, the first IF works just fine but, in case there are more than 2 currencies, I get a NullPointerException on the TRY bit.
None of those methods have a return null so I'm guessing it is something wrong that I am doing on the mapping part to pull the values out.

Here are the other 2 methods that are pulled off:

```
public Money getEquivalent(String targetCurrencyCode) throws CurrencyNotFoundException,ExchangeRateNotFoundException {
    if (this.currencyCode.equals(targetCurrencyCode))   {
        return this;
    }
    return getEquivalent(CurrencyCache.get().getCurrency(targetCurrencyCode));
}
```

and:

```
public long getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, any more info you might need just let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace you get?

Comment: You can change totalAmount = null; to totalAmount = "" in the catch blocks and give a try.why you want to make totalAmount to be null if for a particular iteration of loop is throwing the exception

Comment: You never check for nullability your variable. Something like `money.getValue().getEquivalent(BASE_CURRENCY).getAmount()` could generate a NPE very easily.

Comment: @Andreas: java.lang.NullPointerException at CaptureFileInsertOracle.init(CaptureFileInsertOracle.java:46)

Comment: @KalaiarasanManimaran: Because I will later pass those to the DB and if it can't calculate I want it to be passed as null.

Comment: @eSP - that isn't a stacktrace.  That is just the first line of a stacktrace ... and it doesn't offer any real clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `totalAmount` is nullable, and because it is used in the very first iteration, you need to set it to a non-`null` value before the loop:

```
totalAmount = 0L;
Map<String, Money> totals = captureFile.getTotalMoney();
for (Entry<String, Money> money : totals.entrySet()) {
    try {
        totalAmount = totalAmount + money.getValue().getEquivalent(BASE_CURRENCY).getAmount();
    }
    ... 
}
```

If `totalAmount` is not set to `null` before entering the loop, the first `+=` call would result in an NPE.

Comment: that assumes that totalAmount is a Long or an Integer (we would need to see its declaration to know for sure) - an alternative explanation would be money.getValue() returning null

Comment: @tucuxi There is no assumption here: `totalAmount` is assigned `getAmount()` in the first branch, and OP shows `getAmount()`'s signature, which returns `long`. In the exception handler OP assigns `null` to `totalAmount`, its type must be `Long`.

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong, but why would ```long totalAmount``` (note lowercase L) fail to compile? And why would money.getValue() returning null fail to account for the symptoms?

Comment: @tucuxi if `totalAmount` were `long`, not `Long`, this assignment from the exception handler would not compile: `totalAmount = null;` Returning `null` from `money.getValue()` would definitely account for the symptoms, but I think that it is a lot less likely, because OP uses exceptions rather than returning `null`s in situations where results are unknown (say, because the currency conversion fails).

Comment: ouch - should have seen it. I was looking for my clues further up.

Comment: Will try this approach first as I was under this same impression but disregarded it for some reason. Thanks, will come back with some feedback

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Many thanks, it worked like a charm. A lesson I won't forget (hopefully) =)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying that this line throws an NPE.

```
totalAmount = totalAmount +
         money.getValue().getEquivalent(BASE_CURRENCY).getAmount();
```

There are 4 ways that that can happen:

- if `totalAmount` is declared as `Integer` (or another primitive wrapper type) and it is `null`,
- if `money` is `null`,
- if `money.getValue()` returns `null`,
- if `money.getValue().getEquivalent(BASE_CURRENCY)` returns `null`.

Unfortunately your code is too fragmentary to tell which of these is possible.

It is also possible that the `getEquivalent` is throwing the NPE ... though that would be clear from the stacktrace.

The fact that this line:

```
totalAmount = totalMoney.getAmount();
```

is NOT throwing an NPE doesn't allow us to eliminate *any* of the possibilities listed above.